# Image Resize - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, image-resizing

I wrote the code for uploading to firebase storage directory.I have to resize the selected image by using Javascript. Image should be **65x65** size.

It's my code:

```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                                  if (user) {
                                      //Handling Contact Form
                                      var uploader_profilfotograf = document.getElementById('uploader_profilfotograf');

                                      var fileButton_profilfotograf =        document.getElementById('fileButton_profilfotograf');
                                      fileButton_profilfotograf.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                                          var file = e.target.files[0];

                                          var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profile_images/'+user.uid);
                                          var task = storageRef.put(file);
                                          task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
                                              var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
                                              uploader_profilfotograf.value = percentage;

                                          }, function error(err) {


                                          },function complete() {

                                          });
                                      });


                                  }
                              });
```

Comment: Did you try any of these? https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+resize+image+javascript

Comment: One possibility: doing it in the back-end, i.e. with Cloud Functions. See https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/generate-thumbnail